# Keep fullscreen api in fullscreen after clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, fullscreen

I am using the HTML5 fullscreen API so users can view my website in fullscreen, however when a user clicks a link (such as a menu item) the user switches back to the normal browser mode. How can I keep the browser in fullscreen when the user clicks certain links? Preferably without having to convert the whole website to an AJAX page load system.

Answer (score 5):

It will not be possible to do this without converting to an AJAX loading system. When you navigate to a different page, the DOM tree is destroyed, but the element you are putting into fullscreen mode is part of said DOM tree.