# Fullscreen mode on click? Fullscreen API closes after navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fullscreen

I'm making an offline website for a project and I'd like the whole thing to be displayed in full screen when opened (or after clicking a prompt.) At the moment I use [Fullscreen API](http://qnimate.com/full-screen-api-tutorial-with-demo/) which works great but it exits out of fullscreen after a user navigates to another page.

I've seen that other people have had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720222/keep-fullscreen-api-in-fullscreen-after-clicking-on-a-link) and using Fullscreen API for my purpose may not possible because of the DOM tree being destroyed.

Are there any other work arounds or options I could use to get this working?
Still new at this stuff the vague answers I can find about "Ajax Loaders" has me lost.

Ideally it would be cross browser compatible – I'm handing over the files on USB and I have no control over what browser it will be opened on.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly you want. Do you specifically only want an element fullscreen? When you navigate to a different page, what do you expect to be fullscreen?

Comment: @DylanWatt Sorry, I should have been more clear – I'd like the whole website to be in full screen and kept in fullscreen for the duration of the users session, no matter what page they're on.

Answer (score 0):

From the [offical whatwg spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#traverse-the-history-by-a-delta) (in the section dealing with naviagtion):

> ...If the specified browsing context's active document is not the same
>   Document as the Document of the specified entry, then run these
>   substeps:
>
> 1. Fully exit fullscreen...

I may be misreading this, but I think it's just the spec that if the DOM completely changes (eg page navigation), fullscreen will be dismissed.

You may need to look into something like chromium.

Edit:

As to AJAX loaders, it's basically referring to making your page a "single page app," where you only load your page once, and all of your functionality is driven by javascript. Frameworks like Angularjs are good for this, but it's a large architectural change to make your site operate that way.